# Accessing reducer property with variable

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have an `owner` object property that is common to many parent level objects. That's how I keep it for consistency. Here's a simplified example:

Cat object:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Johnny",
   "owner": {
       "id": 123,
       "name": "Sam",
       "phone": "307-555-1234"
   },
   "gender": "male"
}
```

Car object:

```
{
   "id": "lkj33k3j9992jj21",
   "make": "BMW",
   "model": "535i",
   "owner": {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "Sam",
      "phone": "307-555-1234"
   },
   "mileage": 10
}
```

I'm creating an action that I can use in multiple reducers that will set properties of `owner`. My action looks like this:

```
export const setOwnerProperties = (objectType, id, name, phone) => {
   return {
      type: types.SET_OWNER_PROPERTIES,
      objectType,
      id,
      name,
      phone
   };
}
```

The question is how do I access the `objectType` programmatically in my reducer? I tried the following code but I'm getting a compile error where I have `state.[action.objectType]` in the code below.

```
case types.SET_OWNER_PROPERTIES:
   return Object.assign({}, state, {
      [action.objectType]: Object.assign({}, state.[action.objectType], {
         id: action.id,
         name: action.name,
         phone: action.phone
      })
   })
```

How can I access the `owner` property of `objectType` in my state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks strange, you're using both dot-notation and bracket-notation to do property lookup:

Where you should be doing this:

```
Object.assign({}, state[action.objectType], { ... })
```

You're doing:

```
Object.assign({}, state.[action.objectType], { ... })
```

Comment: Yup! That was the issue! One dot! will create a problem!!! Thank you :-)